# Element's style does not change on click in React

Tags: reactjs

I have been dealing with this issue for days now. I  just do not understand why  element's style does not change I  can see the   event handler is working, the click changes the  "this.style" but  it does not apply to element .

```
import { getByPlaceholderText } from '@testing-library/dom';
import React from 'react';
import {Component} from 'react';
import Element from '../Element/Element'


            class Element extends Component{   // element who has the eventLister click
               render(){
            return <div onClick = {this.props.func} style = {this.props.style}> 
                    HELLO 
                   </div>
                   }
                 }


   class UserInput extends Component{     // here in UserInput I am  returning "Element" above 
                                          // and i am sending the event handler and style as  
                                          //  props
        style = {
        color:'red',
        fontSize:'40px'

         }
       func2=()=>{
          this.style = ({
          color:'black',
      
      });
       console.log('clicked')
       console.log(this.style);
   
 }


render(){ 
    return < Element func = {this.func2.bind(this)} style= {this.style}/>  
}
```

}

```
      export  default UserInput;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing `this.style` does not trigger a rerender, so `Element` component does not see the new style.
You should put the style in the component `state` `this.state = { style: ... }`

And inside `func2` update the state `this.setState({ style: ... })`

And then, the `render` function:

```
render(){ 
    return < Element func = {this.func2.bind(this)} style= {this.state.style}/>  
}
```

Comment: So it means whenever  the state changes the render function of  this element is called?

Comment: Yes, when and only the state or the props changes, react rerenders the component.